# Ajax-Solr not work after change jquery.min.js 1.7.2 to newer version (1.11.2)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, solr

I used an Ajax-solr to display my solr cores. With an old jquery version (1.7.2) everything works properly. Now i should integrate my part with another code, where i should use the version of jquery - 1.11.2. 
As soon as i changed the library version i get following mistake

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: http://10.46.3.100:8982/solr/RMRB/
>       at Function.fb.error (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at fb.tokenize (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at fb.select (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at Function.fb [as find] (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at m.fn.init.find (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at new m.fn.init (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at m (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at child.afterRequest (ResultWidget.js:41)
>       at child.handleResponse (AbstractManager.js:145)
>       at Object.handler (Manager.jquery.js:23)

Answer (score 1):

There is a large gap between jQuery versions 1.7.2 and 1.11.2, and you must have lost some dependencies required to run your version of ajax-solr properly.

As stated in the jQuery blog :

> jQuery went through a major house-cleaning with the 1.9 release that
>   removed some features. If you haven’t yet moved from an earlier
>   version, see the [jQuery 1.9 Upgrade Guide](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/) and let the [jQuery Migrate
>   plugin](http://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme) do all the heavy lifting for you.

You might also want to double check ajax-solr compatibility with jQuery, it seems the plugin is not maintained anymore (last commit in Aug 2016). Edit: On the other side jQuery 1.11.2 was released before (december 2014) so it shouldn't be a big deal if you follow the upgrade guide and if you run the latest ajax-solr.